# How do I extract a large voice memo file off my iPhone and into my mac

Tags: itunes, iphone

How do I extract a large voice memo file off my iPhone and into my mac. It is too large to email.

Answer (score 4):

1. Dock your iPhone via USB.
2. Open itunes.
3. Click the name of your iPhone under Devices in the left column.
4. Click the Music tab.
5. Click the checkbox for Include voice memos.
6. Sync your device.
7. Your files will appear under a new **Voice Memos playlist in iTunes**

Comment: Although this is still the answer posted throughout Apple support forums, it seems not to work reliably, and does not work at all on my PCs.  Using an iPad 7th gen, iOS 16.5, latest iTunes, Windows 10.  I'll post an answer myself if I find a non-paid non-3rd-party solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried @gentmatt's answer and it don't work for me.

Then I downloaded [diskaid](http://www.digidna.net/diskaid) which is fantastic.

Comment: This software now goes by iMazing, and is spammed across Apple support questions across the internet.  It is not free and does not have viable free functionality.